# WPF Label content alignment

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In a WPF label, is aligned like this, that if the font size is increased, the label size increases in **bottom**-right.

[image]

Is there a possibility to make it increase in **top**-right direction?

PS.

The labels are contained in a **`Canvas`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the Vertical Label position within the Canvas with Canvas.Top it will grow downwards when font-size increases. If you specify Vertical position with Canvas.Bottom it will grow upwards. The same goes for Canvas.Left and Canvas.Right.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Bottom and Left properties of the control.

```
<Label Canvas.Bottom="50" Canvas.Left="50">Hello</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

What sort of container is holding your labels?

It looks like you are trying to plot a point on a canvas and add labels. I'd recommend putting both labels in a single panel so they scale together, then just position the panel at the point on the Canvas.

As an alternative, you could look into using a `RenderTransform` on your label instead of a FontSize change. You can Scale the label to a larger size, and set the center point of the Scale to adjust what direction it scales in.

Comment: the container is a Canvas. I can't use a RenderTransform, because user specifies a concrete FontSize.

Comment: If the Labels are contained in something that enforces layout on its contents, like a `StackPanel`, you should be able to maintain margins between the two...

Comment: @djacobson: The labels are contained in a Canvas. I am able, but don't know how right now :)

Comment: @serhio Are the labels contained in their own `Canvas`, or does one large `Canvas` contain all visual elements of the plot? You should just be able to stick the `Labels` into their own `StackPanel` within a larger `Canvas`. Also, how are you tying the labels to the plot points? Have you looked into [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx)?